# Reset root password in mysql galera cluster

Tags: mysql, galera

Pls enlight me, i have mysql cluster and have issue the previous DBA forgot pass root mysql of one node,
if i reset this root pass would it be impact to galera cluster ? if galera cluster using root ?
and how do i reset the root pass in galera cluster in for one of the node?

Thanks.
Tigerpig